# base_url() not working properly in internet explorer (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, base-url

My navigation bar images and links load fine in CHROME but when loading the same page in INTERNET EXPLORER the images don't load but displays the no image icon. The links in IE are like this

CodeIgniter/index.php/news/index.php/news/

instead of just

CodeIgniter/index.php/news

HOWEVER, IE manages to load the css successfully even though that is also using the base_url()... here is my code:

**test.php**

```
<head>
<base href="<?php echo base_url() ?>">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/css/main.css">
</head>
 <nav>
    <ul>

     <li><a href="index.php/news">
     <img src = "public/images/home.png" alt="Home" title="Home"/>
     </a></li>


     <li><a href="index.php/news/create">
     <img src = "public/images/create.png" alt="Create new article" title="Create new article"/>
     </a></li>

    </ul>
 </nav>
```

**config.php**

```
  $config['base_url']   = 'http://localhost/CIgniter/CodeIgniter/';
```

## Answer

Quote:Well Fabios suggestion was successful thanks `<img src = "<?=base_url('public/images/home.png')?>" alt="Home" title="Home"/>` works even though it is gonna be a pain in future. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Well <base> is HTML5. What version of IE do you intend on this working for?

Comment: Instead of loading your images like that load like this <img src = "<?=base_url('public/images/home.png')?>" alt="Home" title="Home"/>

and do the same with the css, and remove the base tag, if you want cross browser compatibility

Comment: base_url() isn't effected by browser, its should be a static...even if your just pluging in $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] or something such.....

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys, I will try Fabios alternative (long winded, ha) attempt, I am running this on IE10 on my home pc atm but will also need it for earlier versions so I assume Fabios is the best way to go thanks. John well I don't know what to say, there are others reporting it across the internet with no simple fix.

Comment: Well Fabios suggestion was successful thanks `<img src = "<?=base_url('public/images/home.png')?>" alt="Home" title="Home"/>` works even though it is gonna be a pain in future. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well Fabios suggestion was successful thanks

`<img src = "<?=base_url('public/images/home.png')?>" alt="Home" title="Home"/>`

works even though it is gonna be a pain in future. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is that you are using relative paths e.g `public/images/home.png` instead of `/public/images/home.png`, the slash at the start tells the browser that it should retrieve content based on the absolute path you've specified at `$config['base_Url'] = ...` instead of the current path it is (I mean you get to `CodeIgniter/index.php/news` and you've specified a relative path to it so that's why it appened to it producing a wrong path `CodeIgniter/index.php/news` + `index.php/news/`)
so when you add a slash at the start of your path it will be refering to the absolute path and it will get to you at `CodeIgniter/index.php/news`.